# How do I add a javascript variable to HTML image src tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, random

I **know** this answer is out here, but I have been unable to find it (or at least *recognize* it when I saw it!).  I'm a relative noob to jquery, so bear with me please.

## Problem:

I have 20 images, named **1.png**  through **20.png**.  I would like a different image to display randomly each time a user clicks a button.

## What's working:

My javascript code to generate the random number looks like this:

```
var randomImage = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
```

## What's not...

What I'm trying to do is pass the result of that to my HTML document as the name of the image, so that is reads something like this:

```
 <img id="randImg" class="img_answer" src="randomImage.png">
```

I tried concatenating, but can't seem to figure this out.  Do I need to create a function that affects the img ID or class? Can anyone point me to the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: That's _Javascript_, not jQuery.

Comment: As @SLaks points out, Javascript is the language running on browsers in general. jQuery is a library that makes doing some things in Javascript easier. Generally if you see $('something here'), that's jQuery - the rest is Javascript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var randomImage = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);    
var imgName = randomImage+".png";
$("#randImg").attr("src",imgName);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a9Ltw/

Comment: Not that much, but it is simpler.

Comment: Thanks Mooseman, and everyone who helped.  Mooseman, your jsfiddle code works like a charm on jsfiddle, but I've got something else causing a problem.  No console errors and the new correct image path flashes briefly in the console, however the image never changes on my site.  I've got more learning to do before I ask for more help, but I wanted to thank everyone who chimed in.  Cheers, Cliff

Comment: @Cliff Happy to help. Please mark a 'best answer' for future users.

Answer (score 4):

Spelling it out a bit to help teach:

On your page you'd have something like this:

```
<img id=randomImage />
```

And probably in the head to hide the image until you've picked one to load, this:

```
<style>
#randomImage {
    width: 400px; height: 200px; /* or whatever the dimensions are */
    visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
```

Then in your Javascript:

```
var ordinal = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
$('#randomImage').css('visibility', 'visible').attr('src', ordinal + '.png');
```

So the HTML lays out the img tag, and some early CSS sets its dimensions and hides it so there's no ugly broken image icon etc in some browsers - just a blank space.

Then eventually the Javascript loads and runs, determining a random ordinal. The second line of Javascript calls jquery to make the img visible and set its src attribute to the random image.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var randomImage = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 20),    
                img = randomImage + ".png";

    $("#randImg").attr("src", img);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add some default image to `img` tag to prevent displaying nothing if user has disabled JavaScript, and then in jQuery use `$("#randImg").attr("src", randomImage + ".png");`

Answer (score 0):

```
var thesoruce = "http://localhost:8080/content/dam/admin/" + id ;

 g_fb.find('p').append('<img src= '+thesoruce +'  height="250px" width="600px">');
```